# Neodynamic Barcode Professional upload error for SSRS report server

Tags: reporting-services, barcode-printing, neodynamic

I am Developing a SSRS Report for Displaying Barcode . I am Using Neodynamic Barcode Proffessional and  the Report is Working fine in Developer Machine (MY Machine). When i try to Upload the Report into SSRS Report Server i get this Error Can any one Help on this. Thanks in Advance

Note : I am Using SSRS 2012 Version and The Report Server is also the Same

Error :

```
Error while loading code module: ‘Neodynamic.ReportingServices.Barcode, Version=7.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c6b33c3093a0d4cd’. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'Neodynamic.ReportingServices.Barcode, Version=7.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c6b33c3093a0d4cd' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) (rsErrorLoadingCodeModule) Get Online HelpError in class instance declaration for class Neodynamic.ReportingServices.Barcode: [BC30002] Type 'Neodynamic.ReportingServices.Barcode' is not defined. (rsCompilerErrorInClassInstanceDeclaration) Get Online Help 
There is an error on line 4 of custom code: [BC30451] Name 'Neodynamic' is not declared. (rsCompilerErrorInCode) Get Online Help
```

Comment: Have you deployed the same DLL to the server that exists on your local machine? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155034.aspx

Comment: Yes ian I have deployed the Same DLL into the Machine

Answer (score 0):

Put your dll `Neodynamic.ReportingServices.Barcode` in

Driver Server Location:`\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.SQLLOCAL\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin`